# bootstrap accordion drupal views

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal

I am creating an FAQ page using the Bootstrap views module in Drupal 7. I want the questions to open accordion style. I have created several block views that contain questions pertinent to one subject (i.e FAQ's about the service, FAQ's about payment, FAQ's about other etc). The accordion is working perfectly for the first block (it is opening and closing on the individual question), but when I try and click FAQ's in the second and third blocks views it is opening the first question from the first block view.  How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Can you add the JS code you're using and the relevant part of the HTML which Drupal generated?

Comment: So that definitely appears to be the problem.  The href and id values are not unique.  The question is there a way through views to actually change the href and id values manually

Comment: to further clarify.  I used the views bootstrap module and created several different block views which I added to a page.  so block 1 is getting unique href and id values, but those values are being repeated for blocks 2, 3, 4, etc. The question is there a way, through views, to actually change the href and id values manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you probably have repeat IDs on those HTML elements which could explain why they're all triggering the events linked to the first element. You'll need to have different IDs for each.

Comment: That is definitely the problem.  I used the views bootstrap module and created several different block views which I added to a page.  so block 1 is getting unique href and id values, but those values are being repeated for blocks 2, 3, 4, etc.  Is there a way to manually change the href and id values through the views interface?  If not how can I go about doing this?

Comment: Thanks Alberto,  this was the problem and I updated the views bootstrap module which gave unique id's and href values